# How to set value in input tag after clear() using selectize js

Tags: javascript, input, selectize.js

Good Morning I am new to selectize.js I want to set value in input tag after using clear function of selectize.js here is my code

```
$('#selectize-update-endUser').selectize()[0].selectize.clear()
const endUsers = "america, japan";
$('#selectize-update-endUser').val(endUsers);
$('#selectize-update-endUser').selectize({
  plugins: ['remove_button'],
  delimiter: ',',
  persist: false,
  create: true,
});
```

Please help me thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solve the problem
Here's the code

```
//set the value to a constant variable and use split function to make the two string separated by comma will become array
 const endUsers = "america, japan".split(',');

//intialize the input tag into selectized        
$('#selectize-update-endUser').selectize({
            plugins: ['remove_button'],
            delimiter: ',',
            persist: false,
            create: true,
        });

  //clear the input that selectized      
  $('#selectize-update-endUser').selectize()[0].selectize.clear()

     //set the value into the input tag that selectized Note: use for loop if the value given is separated in delimeter 
   for (const user of endUsers) {
            $('#selectize-update-endUser').selectize()[0].selectize.createItem(user);
        }
```